# How do I print to a new line in java?

Tags: java

```
boolean valid = false;
String user = txtUser.getText();
String pass = txtPass.getText();
try {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("src/file"); 
    writer.println("The line");
    writer.println(user + "#"  +  pass); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sign Up"complete",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    writer.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

I am making a sign up page and I already have made the login page. The # in the code is used to separate the username to the password. Everything works fine but the problem with this is that every time I sign up it replaces the sign up information I gave the previous time. So if I signed up the first time with the username "greg" and the password "877" it works fine but then if I go on program again and sign up another user with a different username and password, it replaces the first username and pass. I need it to go to new line after every time someone signs up.

Comment: We can help if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The terminology you're looking for is, "how do I append lines to an existing file".

Comment: @DavidPostill I guess the main problem is that `PrintWriter` will always re create the file.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your file with a [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) first:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("src/file", true));
```

Here's the description for the constructor of `FileWriter(String, boolean)`:

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `fileName` - String The system-dependent filename.
> `append` - boolean if `true`, then **data will be written to the end of the file** rather than the beginning

Answer (score 0):

you are using `public PrintWriter(File file)` to write to the file

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File)) says -

```
parameter specifies the file to use as the destination of this writer. If the file 
exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created. 
The output will be written to the file and is buffered.
```

So in your case you need to append text to the contents of the existing file so as Luiggi said `FileWriter` is your friend

```
FileWriter, a character stream to write characters to file. By default, it will 
replace all the existing content with new content, however, when you specified a
true (boolean) value as the second argument in FileWriter constructor, it will keep 
the existing content and append the new content in the end of the file.
```

try in this way

```
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("src/file", true));
```

Comment: Thanks both of you for the help,working perfectly now :)